# Cordova 3.4 Get file info from local root of the phone

Tags: android, file, cordova

I would to know if there is a way to get some info about a file that is on the root folder (in Android **/mnt/sdcard/file.jpg**).
In particular, I would like to get info of the file size or ,if the file is an image the original size (width and height) of the image.

So, knowing the file directory like **"mnt/sdcard/myimage.jpg"** i would like to know some infos.

Is there any way to do this?

Something like this, doesn't work:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("mnt/sdcard/Dock.jpg", function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
        alert("Size = " + fileObj.size);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.
Helmut

Comment: check this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: If its going to work at all, you probably need a leading slash on the filename. If you can't access it via html5, you could always write a Cordova / Phone gap plugin.